# How can I run a command before compiling the packages of the dependencies with `cargo build`?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How do I manipulate Cargo such that it is able to run a set of command or stuff before it starts building each package individually? I want to use Cargo to do something to the source code of each other dependency packages it receives before it builds those dependencies.

Comment: You can use `build.rs` https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html

Comment: You can't edit the source code of dependencies. It might technically be possible to hack it with a build.rs but it will not be reliable. If you need to monkey-patch dependencies then make forks and use a dependency patch in `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: @PeterHall What do you mean by not reliable? I am looking to use a bash command that will run every time a dependency package is pulled and run a script to do some regex matching to replace certain parts. But yeah will check out build.rs documentation as well to see if it fits in my use case

Comment: You don't have much control over _when_ build.rs runs. It is definitely not designed for the purpose you describe. You might struggle to get consistent results.